# can I use dynamic library(shared object) in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

As is known to everyone, static libraries can work well in an Iphone App  and your App can be easily approved by IOS App Store

Unfortunately, the two static libraries I'm using now have the some C functions and variables.

so I compiled them into *.dylib (dynamic libraries), and copy them to "Bundle Resources" in XCode.

```
dylib_handle = dlopen(dylib_path_in_resource_bundle, RTLD_LAZY);
func = dlsym(dylib_handle, "func");

// invoke func();
```

This works well in simulator and Ipad (of course, different dynamic libraries).

I noticed that somebody said Iphone app does not support any third party dynamic libraries and my app will be rejected. (see here)

but I carefully read the "App Store Review Guidelines", I found no item meet my question.

I'm confused now!

Does iphone app support dynamic libraries? Does IOS AppStore allow this?

Who can give me an official response.

Comment: What does C functions and variables have to do with not being able to use it as a static library now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you build dynamic libraries for iOS and load them at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Bernardo Ramos states in a comment: "Since iOS8 we can use dynamic libraries".

Dynamic libraries are not allowed by the App Store.  No code may be loaded at run-time.  The answer is to convert them to static libraries and compile them into the application.

From iPhoneOSTechOverview:

"If you want to integrate code from a framework or dynamic library into your application, you should link that code statically into your application’s executable file when building your project."

Read "should" as "must"

See SO Answer: [Can create dynamic library for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-create-dynamic-library-for-ios/4733885#4733885)

Comment: This answer is only valid for older iOS versions. Since iOS8 we can use dynamic libraries

Answer (score 1):

No, dynamic libraries are not allowed.

But you can create static libraries, and even "static frameworks" (that is, like a classic framework is, a folder with the ".framework" extension and containing your Headers, resource files if any, and the lib itself, except that your lib must be a static library).