# intergate dylib file in xcode project and read from it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am having a problem to integrate a dylib file into my xcode project.
My application need to read directly from a dylib file from its path using `"handle = dlopen(libPath, RTLD_LAZY);"`
When I insert the file into the project in Resources folder with "Add -> Add Existing File" the file is shown as a framework (or library) and the file does not exist in the file system so that i can read it directly. any solution for that please. Hope I have well explained the problem.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't even think of that. Using your own `dylib` on iOS devices is prohibited by Apple, and will be rejected. See [this Q&A at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-create-dynamic-library-for-ios), too.

Comment: Thank you Yuji for the response. so can I use a static One (.a) and do I need to consider the fact that iPhone uses ARMv7 processor and not intel if I am going to generate the static library ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, use a static library. But how to use a static library should be another independent question on StackOverflow. I'm sure it's already been asked before. Just search on it in the search box above.