# DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, info.plist

I understand that Apple doesn't support using dynamic libraries in iPhone applications. But we are working on a in-house application and we have a unique requirement to use the dynamic libraries. Our requirement is to load a dynamic library as part of "iPhone" application start up. I read that DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES is meant for this purpose. So I edited the Info.plist and added below entry.
       LSEnvironment
        
                DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
                @executable_path/sample.dylib

But it does not seem to be working. Can you please let me know your thoughts ? Really appreciate your help in this regard.

Thanks
--Neo

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I also have something that would be fixed rather elegantly by running a dylib at start up for an enterprise app.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way to successfully add `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` load command to a MachO binary using [`optool`](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool).

```
$ optool install -c load -p "@executable_path/<dylib_path>" -t <executable>
$ otool -L <executable>
```

When building `optool`, make sure that build setting `OTHER_LDFLAGS` includes `-ObjC`.

`optool` does not seem to be able to successfully add load commands for `arm64` architectures, so you may want to remove `arm64` from the binary

```
$ lipo <input_file> -remove arm64 -output <output_file>
```

**Edit:**
There is an open [pull request](https://github.com/alexzielenski/optool/pull/1) with support for arm64.

Answer (score 0):

I also working on the same problems for last few days. I also didn't succeed to do it the way you try. So I try to launch my app from another app using this link:
[Dynamic Library injection](http://tackoverflow.com/questions/7910694/dyld-insert-libraries-and-iphone)
,unfortunately Apple Block running multiple tasks (even on iphone simulators) but you can try maybe you will have more luck. I know its not a answer you expect but maybe it will give you some way to think. Please share if you have some progress.

Answer (score -1):

You "could" load a binary at runtime and you can manipulate xcode settings to make it compile dylibs for iOS. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509453/784387

Comment: I think that the main idea is to include Dynamic library without having the app code(source files).

Answer (score -2):

Happy to be corrected, but dylibs are not supported and will not work. You need to get the code for the libraries and compile them into a static lib for the arm6/7 architecture. Then you can easily include these libs. There are plenty of examples of static libs and XCode also provides targets for building them.

Comment: There is no issue in using dylibs in the code. I verified and its working if I include the dylib during build time. My issue is only level deeper. I need the dylib to be loaded as part of application launch. PS: Apple doesn't approve the application if it uses dylib. As I mentioned earlier, our requirement is for an in house app development.