# Libltdl on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any precompiled libltdl available for the iOS or any ideas how to port it for use on iPhone?

Currently I have modified it a bit, but it fails with linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

"*lt*_slist_box", referenced from:
      _lt_dlloader_add in lt_dlloader.o
  "*lt*_slist_cons", referenced from:
      _lt_dlloader_add in lt_dlloader.o
  "*lt*_slist_concat", referenced from:
      _lt_dlloader_add in lt_dlloader.o
  "*lt*_slist_find", referenced from:
      _lt_dlloader_find in lt_dlloader.o
      _lt_dlloader_remove in lt_dlloader.o
  "*lt*_slist_remove", referenced from:
      _lt_dlloader_remove in lt_dlloader.o
  "*lt*_slist_unbox", referenced from:
      _lt_dlloader_remove in lt_dlloader.o
  "*lt*_argz_create_sep", referenced from:
      _argzize_path in ltdl.o
  "*lt*_argz_insert", referenced from:
      _lt_argz_insert in ltdl.o
  "*lt*_argz_append", referenced from:
      _lt_argz_insert in ltdl.o
  "*lt*_argz_stringify", referenced from:
      _lt_dlpath_insertdir in ltdl.o
  "*lt*_argz_next", referenced from:
      _foreach_dirinpath in ltdl.o
      _foreachfile_callback in ltdl.o
  "_preopen_LTX_get_vtable", referenced from:
      _lt_dlinit in ltdl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Maybe your library is compiled only for the target (iPhone) and not for the simulator? The other guess is that you don't link against some utility object file / source file or they are missing from your lib.

Comment: See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-create-dynamic-library-for-ios