# Where are the iOS frameworks binaries located in the filesystem?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm kind of confused about frameworks on iOS. I think they are basically a directory containing a dynamic library, headers and resources.

But in my device the frameworks directories in System/Library/Frameworks don't contain the dynamic library. How is this possible? Shouldn't it be present to be loaded in memory when the application requiring it is launched?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The binaries no longer exist on-device (and have not since iOS 3.1): Apple has merged them all into one large `mmap()`'ed cache file, to make app launch a bit more efficient. As the pages usually never change, the kernel can effectively share them between every running image. You can still use `dlopen()` on files held within the cache, as `dyld` short-circuits file lookup when the given library exists in the cache.

The cache file is in `/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld`, and is named after the architecture (`armv6` or `armv7`). The libraries within can be extracted using [dsc_extractor](http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-195.6/launch-cache/dsc_extractor.cpp) or KennyTM's dyld_decache, available [in this repository](https://github.com/kennytm/Miscellaneous), but once extracted they can't actually be loaded into memory properly (as they all effectively get their symbol tables merged in the cache.)

There's a bit of a better (though older and less informed, more in-depth) write-up here: http://blog.howett.net/2009/09/cache-or-check/.

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed this, too.  Strange.  I can't explain to you "where they are", but I have observed, for example:

If I list out a (private) framework directory:

```
iPhone4:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework root# ls -alt
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root wheel   28 Nov  4  2011 CodeResources -> _CodeSignature/CodeResources
drwxr-xr-x   3 root wheel  170 Nov  2  2011 ./
drwxr-xr-x   2 root wheel  102 Nov  2  2011 _CodeSignature/
-rw-r--r--   1 root wheel  740 Nov  2  2011 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x 170 root wheel 5814 Dec 31  2007 ../

iPhone4:/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework root# ls -alt _CodeSignature/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root wheel  170 Nov  2  2011 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 root wheel  102 Nov  2  2011 ./
-rw-r--r-- 1 root wheel 1222 Nov  2  2011 CodeResources
```

You don't see a `BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager` dylib file.  **However, this code does actually work** to dynamically open that framework, as if that file exists:

```
handle = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Using the `find` command from the root filesystem ("/") location also finds no file on the device named **BluetoothManager**.

I know that's probably not the answer you're looking for, but depending on **why** you want to know, maybe it helps?

Comment: How did you execute a ls command on iPhone4, was the phone jailbroken?

Comment: @gabbler, yes, this was a jailbroken iPhone 4, with ssh access enabled.