# otool -L issue on jailbroken iPhone

Tags: jailbreak, dylib, otool

i connects my jailbroken iPhone which ssh and performs

```
otool -L /Applications/AppStore.app/AppStore
```

and the here is the output

```
/Applications/AppStore.app/AppStore:
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppStoreUI.framework/AppStoreUI (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 993.0.0)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStoreUI.framework/iTunesStoreUI (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2380.17.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 173.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 793.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

and then i perfrom

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/
```

the dir includes:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root wheel    204 Aug 16 23:16 ./
drwxr-xr-x 54 root wheel   1836 Feb 12  2013 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel    861 Dec 17  2012 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x  2 root wheel    102 Dec 17  2012 _CodeSignature/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root wheel    102 Dec 17  2012 en.lproj/
-rw-r--r--  1 root wheel 126648 Aug 16 23:13 tokruleLE.data
```

their has no **CoreFoundation**

and i perfrom

```
find / | grep CoreFoundation
```

there is no a file called **CoreFoundation** too,
i thought **CoreFoundation** should be a dylib. but why cann't i find it. if it's not
a dylib what exactly it is?
of course my AppStore works well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are the iOS frameworks binaries located in the filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830488/where-are-the-ios-frameworks-binaries-located-in-the-filesystem)