# how do i get library path in MacOS?

Tags: macos, dylib

I write a program and i view the dependent libraries, it show in '/usr/lib/', but there is not exists.

```
$ otool -L test
test:
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
```

but, it don't exists:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
ls: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib: No such file or directory
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the iOS frameworks binaries located in the filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830488/where-are-the-ios-frameworks-binaries-located-in-the-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the name of the library in your device is different, just open the terminal and write :
cd library
then write :
pwd
then you will get a library path.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).