# Dynamically load libspotify on ios

Tags: ios, jailbreak, spotify, xbmc

I'm working on an addon for the XBMC media center.

The addon itself is written in python and relies on the ctypes module for accessing the functions of libspotify. The problem is that I've found a roadblock on the iOS platform, as the libspotify build for it is a static library instead of a dylib, and thus, cannot be loaded on runtime by the ctypes module.

I'm aware that bundling iOS apps with code that relies on dylibs would cause an immediate rejection from Apple, but I think that this restriction won't affect this plugin, as XBMC runs only on jailbroken devices.

So the question is:

Is it possible to dynamically load the current (static) build of libspotify on ios?

Perhaps creating a separate dylib and statically linking libspotify to it will do the trick?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *addon* is able to load iOS dylibs, then I don't see why you couldn't build a dylib wrapper for the libspotify.a library.

Make a project in Xcode that's a dylib project, for iOS.  See [my answer here on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509453/119114).  That dylib would then link against libspotify.a.