# IOS - Execute external bundles/libraries at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, runtime, bundle, libraries

I've read lots of things about if it's possible or not.. and I'm a bit confused :S

I'm trying to download from a server a bundle, or something like that and execute it at runtime (a xib with its controllers and own libs). 
There are people that says that is possible but not allowed at apple store, other says that there is no way.. 
It doesn't matter if I can't store it in apple store.

If it's possible, how can I create the bundle or executable file?
How can I link it from the main project?

Thanks!

Comment: Apple has done everything technically feasible to make this an impossible task - its why iOS is considered "sandboxed". If you figure out how to do it you can become rich by selling the technique (until Apple closes that hole).

Comment: What about this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-create-dynamic-library-for-ios
(last comment)

Comment: Right, he says the technology is there to dynamically link, but that when Apple finds your app using that code it won't approve it.

Comment: Ok ok.. but if I dont want to put it at apple store, only for internal use.. its ok, right?

Comment: Ah, yes - if for your own use then sure np. I will guess you can distribute it ad hoc too.