# Is there a way for dlopen to reload a dylib file on iOS?

Tags: ios, dylib, dlopen

As the title says... I'm interested in `dlopen()`. I understand this isn't allowed by the app store but I'm curious about this on iOS.

The issue I have is that I can create a .dylib file and I can load this file at runtime with the following code

```
char *dylibPath = "/Applications/myapp.app/mydylib2.dylib";

void *libHandle = dlopen(dylibPath, RTLD_NOW);
if (libHandle != NULL) {
    NSString * (*someMethod)() = dlsym(libHandle, "someMethod");
    if (someMethod != NULL)  {
        NSLog(someMethod());
    }
    dlclose(libHandle);
}
```

This is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime/10509453#10509453).

The problem I have is that if I change mydylib2.dylib, `dlopen` doesn't load the recompiled .dylib file. Instead, it resolves an old version of the function `someMethod`.

For example, if `someMethod` first returns `@"Hello"` and I change this to be `@"Hello World"` and recompile, the code above will always return `@"Hello"` until I restart the app in the simulator.

Do any know why this is the case? and suggest a workaround so the this .dylib can be reloaded at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlclose.3.html) for `dlclose` it looks like there are a couple of reasons why the library wouldn't be unloaded.

> There are a couple of cases in which a dynamic library will never be
>   unloaded: 1) the main executable links against it, 2) An API that does
>   not supoort unloading (e.g. NSAddImage()) was used to load it or some
>   other dynamic library that depends on it, 3) the dynamic library is
>   in dyld's shared cache.

I suspect your issue is the "dyld shared cache."  You could try running:

```
sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force
```

after you've replaced the library (not sure if this is available on the iOS though).

Have you checked the return value of `dlclose` to see if it was successful or failed?

Comment: `update_dyld_shared_cache` doesn't seem to be readily available in iOS (and can't find it in Cydia).