# iosopendev logo tweak build error

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweak, logos

I have just created a logos tweak using iOSOpenDev without making any changes to anything. I am getting this error whenever I try to build:

> target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.library.dynamic', but there's  no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did iOSOpenDev install with an error?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is misconfigured with your iOSOpenDev installation, because it *should* allow you to create a `dylib`.

That said, if you follow [the instructions in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10509453/119114), you can manually tweak some settings files to override the default (which doesn't allow dylibs to be built for iOS).  This may need to be done each time you reinstall/upgrade Xcode.