# can we use .so files through flutter for making iOS app?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Am new to flutter would like to know can we use .so files in flutter project to make apps for iOS? I have a native android app that is making use of .so file would like to make similar app for iOS using the same .so file. I don't know can make use of .so apps through flutter for making iPhone apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a regular plugin to integrate to Swift/ObjC to mimic what the existing app does. Or try `ffi` to talk to the so directly.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it. Will read about ffi. Can you please elaborate about use a regular plugin?

Comment: Rereading the question, that so is for Android. You'll need the equivalent framework or dylib for iOS.

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks for your reply. Am bit confused after your recent reply. can you please let me know If I have an .so file is it possible to use it in ios application through flutter as earlier suggested by you by using ffi or any other means. Please reply. Thanks

Comment: You can use that so on Android, but for iOS you'd need the equivalent, which normally has the extension dylib. Where did you get this Android `so` file from? Do they have an iOS version?

Comment: @RichardHeap Am an android app developer. Recently started learning flutter to replicate the app that I have made in Android into iOS. Some of my apps are using an .so file for processing few files.  As am new to flutter am not sure it's possible to use .so file or not for making iOS app. I don't have precompiled code of that so file so cannot modify it. Is it possible to convert .so file to dylib file or can we use .so file through ffi for iOS app? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't believe so. I think you need to get an iOS compatible version from the same place you got the Android so file.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615973/using-shared-object-file-in-ios-so-file

Comment: @RichardHeap Thanks for reply.  As of now it seems impossible to use .so file for iOS. I will research more about it. God bless you.