# iOS App doesn't pass validation isinf and isnan

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, appstore-approval, dicom

[image]

**isinf** and **isnan** are supported in cmath I think. But my app doesn't pass due to this as reported during the validation. My app uses dcmtk compiled as a static library. And there are many apps that use dcmtk and are iOS apps. I tried removing the offending code but without success from the static library.

I posted this on forum.dcmtk.org and still await a reply. Thought I would post this here for more  ideas.

Any ideas on how to resolve this or should I notify Apple?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include the source code instead of the static library? If I am not mistaken, static libraries are generally not allowed, but including the source and compiling it yourself is fine.

Comment: @Paul Maybe you are mistaken? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used std::isnan and std::isinf to pass the validation. That's the answer to only one part of the question i.e., how to validate the project that uses isnan and isinf.

The other part of the question is what I need help with. Why would std::isnan and std::isinf be accepted and not its non std variants? I will make another question out of this I guess.