# SDK versions testing

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

Let's imagine - we have some `SDK` and a lot of released versions.

SDK includes static lib and headers, of course I can't build different versions in one project because of conflicts in class names etc...

We need to test all of them each time and purpose of testing NOT SDK itself.

I was asked to put all of released `SDKs` to one application and allow to switch between them.

I can create separate `projects/targets` and provide different `ipa` to install with different SDK's versions.

So my question - is that possible to create just ONE `iOS` project which generates `iOS` application to launch and switch between `SDK` versions to test? How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you referring to the Apple iOS SDK itself, or a third party SDK? If you mean the iOS SDK, what you are asking is not possible, if you mean a third party SDK, it maybe but more details will be needed. How is the SDK packaged (framework, static object, or other) ?

Comment: sorry, I missed lot of required information, question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you won't be able to link different versions of your SDK in the *same* app. [3rd party libraries and frameworks are statically linked.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4733847/643383) You can, however, create a single project that has several targets, each of which builds a version of the app with a different version of your SDK.

Your case seems like a great candidate for automated unit testing. If you build a suite of unit tests that exercise your SDK, you could easily and automatically run those tests against each version of the test app.

Comment: But people who want to do those tests - they require UI on iPhone only, NO XCODE, NO OTHER TOOLS for test executing... That's a problem

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you'll be building a group of apps for them.