# Can I include a library as a static library and compile it inside a iOS project?

Tags: c++, ios, titanium, static-libraries

I'm programming a C++ library which is going to be used by .NET, Android and iOS. I recently noticed that with external libraries Apple may reject the final App.

It is possible to compile an included library (like Boost, libcurl, sqlite3, etc) as a static library and be able to publish the iOS app with the C++ library (which will include the libraries)?

Comment: static linking is default way to link library for iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem with linking a static library in your project. Only apps using dynamic libraries are rejected by Apple.

[Can you build dynamic libraries for iOS and load them at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime)

Comment: So the C++ library will include the static library (sqlite3 for example) and iOS project will include the C++ library as a static library too.

Comment: Actually in one of my projects I have a custom C++ library that uses boost and sqlite3 but they are included separately in the Xcode project (as separate .a files).