# Can an iOS application be deployed to the appstore with a dylib file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, app-store

Will an iOS app be rejected if an application is deployed with a dylib file? It is a required file for this JXLS (a spreadsheet file creator) framework to work. And if not, what ways are there around it so that I can deploy my application and still have this framework work without the dylib file?

The dylib in question is the : `libc++.dylib` file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you build dynamic libraries for iOS and load them at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime)