# Load xib file from framework

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I'm creating some code which I've sorted into a framework - purely because I want to reuse this code elsewhere (other osx apps - not iOS).

Inside my Resources folder I created a xib file. One level higher in my root I have the corresponding Controller file.

If my client app is using storyboards - how would I go about loading this view? Note I did manage to access properties on the mentioned controller so I did all the hook up etc as described in Apple docs and elsewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note. I have a ViewController which was created by default in the host/client app. I've set the controller to inherit from the controller class defined in my framework (the one associated with the view I wish to load)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the resources in a *.bundle, not a framework. 
Just create a new target that's a bundle.

Then load the nibs with:

```
NSString *resourceBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myBundle" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourceBundlePath];

// load View Controller from that
UIViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:resourceBundle];
```

Comment: Thanks Michal. Yea I was pointed in this direction after someone, somewhere else mentioned 'dynamic libraries'. It sounds to me that bundles are the predecessor to frameworks (eventhough Apple have been using them for some time) -- however as you've mentioned and showed you will access them in the same way. Appreciate your help though :)

Comment: No problem. For future reference: you can't use dynamic libraries (*.dylib) in iOS because you will get rejected from the app store. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504617/will-appstore-reviewers-allow-us-to-use-dynamic-library-in-ios8

Comment: let bundle = NSBundle(identifier:"com.moblejoseph.New")
        let controller = UIViewController(nibName:"MyViewController", bundle: bundle!)
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**: Here is a sample to load xib to create a view in the framework:

1. Create a new bundle (eg: MyBundle.bundle) and put your all resources (such as: xib, images, audio files, etc) into the new bundle.
2. Load xib:

   ```
   NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
   NSString* path = [resourcePath 
   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyBundle.bundle"];
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
   if(bundle)
   {
       self.view = [[bundle loadNibNamed:@"MyXibNameWithoutSuffix" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
   } else {
       self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
   loadNibNamed:@"MyXibNameWithoutSuffix" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
   }
   ```
3. Load image:

   ```
   UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBundle.bundle/MyImageName"];
   if(nil == image) {
      image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageName"];
   }
   ```
4. If you're using cocopods, please make sure the s.resources has been
   set in .podspec file.

   ```
   s.resources = "MyBundle.bundle/**/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,storyboard,xib,xcassets,plist}"
   ```