# Is it possible to load shared dynamic frameworks when they are actually needed?

Tags: ios, frameworks, dynamic-linking, dlopen, dyld

I am trying to decrease the amount of time it takes for the application to load. First of all, I modularized a lot of the application's code into static Libraries and then I embedded them into one single Shared Core Dynamic Framework that gets loaded by the application and its extensions. So, at this point I only have 1 Dynamic Library that dyld needs to take care of.

But I am still not happy with the loading times of my application. I was wondering if its possible by some of the dyld APIs to load an Apple Shared Framework when its needed instead of loading it before main.

Lets say for example CoreTelephony. If I only use CoreTelephony in one single flow in my app, and most of users don't even get to that flow, could I prevent dyld from loading that shared Framework and then load it myself only when I need to?

Comment: [Can you build dynamic libraries for iOS and load them at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4733847)