# Why do we have this confusing setup about Static Library and Framework in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have read many articles about static/dynamic library/framework. So my understanding is (let me know if it's inaccurate):

```
Framework = Library + Bundle
Static = Linking at build time
Dynamic = Linking at run time
```

In Xcode, we have "Static Library" and "Framework". Which raises a few confusing points:

- Why there's no "Dynamic Library" option?
- Given that we can already link framework statically, why do we still need a "Static Library"? (isn't StaticFramework = StaticLibrary + Bundle? )

Comment: There is not *static framework* - framework is *always* dynamic

Comment: @Asperi in cocoapods, there's a static linkage setting for frameworks: `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many concepts that must be clear

Libraries have two categories based on how they are linked to the executable file

1. Static library `.a`, `.so`.  link at compile time. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library)
2. Dynamic libraries `.dylib` `.dll` etc.  link at runtime. only apple can use it for iOS for some safe [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime), we cannot build this.

ps, a special kind in apple platform

Text Based `.dylib` stubs — `.tbd`

Framework

Framework is a package that can contain resources such as dynamic libraries, strings, headers, images, storyboards etc.
vs Libraries, Framework has more [features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148747/what-is-the-difference-between-a-framework-and-a-library)

Framework also has static and dynamic

iOS 8 later, we can use a dynamic framework, why Apple releases this. maybe [Extension and App share code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)
this Dynamic Framework for iOS is named embedded frameworks, because when we build the app copy the framework in app bundle.
so the embedded framework is different from system dynamic Frameworks like `UIKit.Framework`

> Why there's no "Dynamic Library" option?

the embedded library is allowed with the `Framework` option, but dynamic framework shared in muti app is also not allowed

> Given that we can already link framework statically, why do we still need a "Static Library"? (isn't StaticFramework = StaticLibrary + Bundle? )

well, Xcode not only support Objective-c and Swift, but also support C, C++ which may use the static library

Answer (score 3):

> Why there's no "Dynamic Library" option?

Because Dynamic Library is [not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime) for iOS apps at beginning.

> Given that we can already link framework statically, why do we still need a "Static Library"? (isn't StaticFramework = StaticLibrary + Bundle? )

Because old Xcode only support `Static Library`.

`Static Framework` was added later, and they keep the `Static Library`.