# How can I wrap two libraries in Xcode 4 into another library and use the wrapper library

Tags: iphone, xcode4, static-libraries

How can I wrap two libraries `(libA and libB)` in **Xcode 4** into another library `(libCWrapper)` and use the wrapper library `(libCWrapper)` without having to include the headers of `libA and libB`  in my project

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid having to include headers somehow.  That either means altering the header search path, including them in your project, or wrapping the static libraries plus headers in a framework.

Comment: It sounds like wrapping the static libraries plus headers in  a framework might be the best option.  but how do it do that ?

Comment: The resources for doing so are a bit sketchy, but try starting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way