# Statically combining C++ libraries

Tags: c++, ios, poco, static-linking

I created an iOS framework with a combined, universal static C++ library from the [Poco](http://pocoproject.org/) sources by using `lipo` and `libtool`. Essentially, what I do is :

```
compile Poco for iPhoneOS and iPhoneSimulator

for each architecture:
  libtool -static -o libPoco.a libPocoFoundation.a libPocoNet.a libPocoJSON.a

lipo armv6/libPoco.a armv7/libPoco.a i386/libPoco.a -create -output universal/libPoco.a

create a framework from the generated fat library and includes
```

Look at [besport/PocoMobile](https://github.com/besport/PocoMobile/blob/master/Build-iOS-Framework.sh) for more information.

Now, I tried using this framework in an app and everything sounded fine. But when I try to use a class from Poco, the linker spits out undefined symbols from both Poco and libstdc++ :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "Poco::format(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Any const&)", referenced from:
      Poco::Logger::warning(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Any const&) in MapStorage.o
  "Poco::Message::Message(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Message::Priority)", referenced from:
      Poco::Logger::log(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, Poco::Message::Priority) in MapStorage.o
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      Poco::ProcessImpl::launchByForkExecImpl(std::string const&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, std::string const&, Poco::Pipe*, Poco::Pipe*, Poco::Pipe*, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&) in Poco(Process.o)
      Poco::EnvironmentImpl::setImpl(std::string const&, std::string const&) in Poco(Environment.o)
      Poco::EnvironmentImpl::hasImpl(std::string const&) in Poco(Environment.o)
      Poco::EnvironmentImpl::getImpl(std::string const&) in Poco(Environment.o)
  "std::string::empty() const", referenced from:
  ...
```

I verified with `nm` and `libtool -info`, and the library file seems to contain the right functions. The Objective-C++ files I have in the project compile fine as well if I don't do anything with Poco.

- Does this have to do the libraries being C++ libraries? Any compiler flag I have to turn on?
- Can `libtool -static` actually use .a libraries? Am I doing that right?

Comment: You created a framework using a static library rather than a dynamic library?

Comment: Yup. AFAIK you can't use dynamic libraries on iOS...

Comment: I wasn't aware you could have a static library within a framework however.

Comment: Well apparently you can. It is a nice way to organize external libraries and headers ;)

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?