# How can i create a framework from a third party framework and my source code?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, static-libraries

i compile opencv from source code to opencv2.framework file. And i wrote some code that using opencv2.framework. Now, i have to create package from my code for third party developer.

mysource(objective-c) + opencv2.framework(compiled from c++) => package => thirparty developer will use that.

(it can be **two seperate framework** or **a static library+opencv2.framework** or **one framework file together**)

Comment: What have you tried already? Where did you fail? Did you look at the other posts regarding packaging frameworks, e.g. this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way

Comment: make your framework but do not add the first framework in your framework. give the other framework to your clients and let them add both the framework. Infact it increases the transparency of the frameworks you have used.

Comment: i have tried some tutorial. Expecially, this one https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework . But throwed a lot of error. And adding libc++ and libstdc++ solved my all problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can have your own custom framework and the client can add both framework to the project and compile with no errors. [You can see how to create a framework here](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-create-custom-ios-framework.html). just create a bundle target and add the files you want to include in your framework. add new aggrigated target copy the lipo script and you will get a framework done