# Creating an SDK or API from an app to run in another app

Tags: ios, api, sdk

I have been contacted by a company installing iPads in hotels, they are developing an app that has many apps with different functionality. There developer is asking for an SDK or API of our app to include in there system. i have never heard of this. Does anyone know how to go about this or if it is even possible to do?

Our app is a complex clock radio, Beautiful Clock Radio for the iPad.

Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following links

1. [Creating Static Libraries For iOS](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)
2. [How to build a framework or library for other developers, the
   secure way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way)
3. [Creating the Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html)

And I hope this would help you! :)