# How to hide code in implimentation file in iOS

Tags: ios, shared-libraries

I have a developed a generic class and I want to give it to one of my friend.

How can I hide the code so that he should not view the logic in that. Can I do something like apple does by giving us only the `.h` files.

Please help me in achieving this. Thanks.

Comment: You will have to make library (framework) for this.

Comment: How to do that after that can we send only .h file

Comment: After that you will have to add framework same like you do for inbuilt frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your own static library i.e. `.a` file in `xcode`. And it is not very tough, you can do this in just in few mins.

Read this tutorial and try in out:

[How to make `Universal Static library` (`.a` file) in iOs using `xCode`](http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-make-universal-static-library.html)

Comment: I'm still able to use breakpoint and select step into to view the code in .m file. (I'm only importing a .a file together with the .h file)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make your own `library` (framework) for this.
You can search about it there are many tutorials about that. One of them is [How to build a framework or library for other developers, the secure way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way)

**Edit: Great Tutorial**
[Creating Static Libraries For iOS](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/)