# Create ios static library with with more classes

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4, ios6

I want to develop iOS static library and distribute to other developers.

I have started some R&D and found only one way to create static library with only one class which is having header file and implementation file.

I would like to create static library with more individual classes. Now we are creating static libraries with only header files and implementation files.

Is it possible to add XIB files also to that? Can anyone guide me to solve this requirement?

Comment: May be this answer will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4065131/1095923

Comment: Read this. http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/#adding_projects_to_a_workspace

Comment: Hi , did you find any solution for that ?  I am facing the same but not getting anything

Comment: Hey... Actually I ahad a thought of doing it long back. But unfortunately it didnt work out.Better you can create custom classes and try to reuse them for development.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, you have created static library, then you just need to add more files. Suppose you can want to make some file to make public to developers then you need to make it public scope.

This may help you...   http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules