# How to distribute Swift binary for public consumption?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'd like to create a Swift framework that others can import into their project and use, but I don't want to distribute the source code. I'd like to be able to distribute a binary and allow others to import the module and use the functions. Is this possible?

Note: I'm coming from .NET where you can build an entire project into a single .dll file and allow others to simply reference it.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/26/creation-of-pure-swift-module/) would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a framework or library for other developers, the secure way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way)