# How to restrict access to .m file of an ios framework while debugging an app?

Tags: ios, debugging, frameworks

I have created a framework and importing that into a sample application for testing purpose. When I am debugging the application and click on "STEP INTO", I am able to see the contents of .m file of my framework. what is the possible solution to restrict the access to my .m file ??![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode have options of visibility for framework as

- Public: The interface is finalized and meant to be used by your product’s clients. A public header is included in the product as readable source code without restriction.
- Private: The interface isn’t intended for your clients or it’s in early stages of development. A private header is included in the product, but it’s marked “private.” Thus the symbols are visible to all clients, but clients should understand that they're not supposed to use them.
- Project: The interface is for use only by implementation files in the current project. A project header is not included in the target, except in object code. The symbols are not visible to clients at all, only to you.

However, as you mentioned you want something else which secure your code as well so check the post:
[How to build a framework or library for other developers, the secure way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065052/how-to-build-a-framework-or-library-for-other-developers-the-secure-way)